# Как исправить такую ошибку с кодировкой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 455, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 513, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 479, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 118, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 69, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 30, in send_text
    print("\u0412\u044b\u0432\u043e\u0434 \u0441\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0430\u0439\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0446\u0435\u043b\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0447\u0438\u0441\u043b\u0430 ", result)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте `#coding=utf8` в начало файла скрипта.

Comment: Если это не сработает, то: # - * - coding: utf-8 - * -
       Только без пробелов между дефисами и звёздочками